# Generating PSD for an existing site

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver, photoshop

I have a existing parent website and I have to design a new website with similar theme and css styles, though pixel-perfect accuracy is not required, the look and feel should be somewhat similar.

I came across the way of converting PSD to HTML and CSS3 and I have access to adobe tools.

I though if I can get the PSD of the parent site I can use the design for coding the new website.

Is there a way to get the PSD of the current website without having access to the code repository of the parent website, I just can access the parent website.

Comment: No - that is simply not the way to go.  Why not just get the HTML and CSS of the original site.  Anyone with a browser can get those off the internet.  If you convert HTML to PSD and then back to HTML, you're going to end up with a big mess.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So you suggest to get the HTML and CSS from  the browser and try to salvage what parts are considered necessary.

Comment: If you're trying to generate the same look, you should be able to grab all the main elements of the page and CSS and just change the content.  For example, header and footer could remain nearly identical with just different links/images.  Also, you need the same HTML/CSS if you want the second site to behave the same at different screen sizes, window sizes, mobile devices.

Comment: So getting the main HTML/CSS elements and changing the content should be enough to get the same look and feel initially.

Comment: Yep, assuming your content fits in the layout or the layout is flexible enough to adapt to your content.  If it doesn't fit, then you have a starting point that you can tweak the CSS on.

Answer (score 0):

Another I dea that I have used in the past is to take a screen shot of the original Website, and place it as as the bottom layer (At reduced opacity) in Photoshop, and just sort of build the new site over it. With clever use of guides you can maintain the feel and flow of the original site.

It also places the original site so you are able to conveniently use the eye dropper tool, in order to maintain the original color scheme.